# Rendering a partial multiple times in Handlebars+Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, viewengine

I'm quite new to the world of Node and Handlebars and have managed to get a single partial rendering in Node doing the following:

```
response.render('index', 
        {  
            'data': data, 
            partials: 
            {
                results: 'results'
            }
        });
```

and in my html page I have the following

```
{{> results}}
```

Which renders my results.html partial. But now I need to have the same partial rendering on the index page multiple times each with a different set of data, I've tried the following:

```
response.render('index', 
        {  

            partials: 
            {
                'data': data,
                results: 'results'
            }
        });
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: What exactly happened (compared to what you expected)?

Comment: I was expecting (or thought would happen) that the data I'm passing through to the partial would be rendered and then I can render that the partial again with different data eg place into a function to be called.

Comment: And what did happen instead when you tried the above code?